# Why does my poission distribution return infinity values

Tags: python, python-3.x, poisson

I'm trying to calculate Poisson distributed arrival times in python.
I've made the following function:

```
from scipy.stats import poisson
import random
import math

def pois_Arrival(ticker):
    m = 15
    p = random.randint(1,100) / 100
    x = poisson.ppf(p, mu = m)
    if x >= 1:
        x = math.trunc(x)
    else:
        x = 1
    arrival = x + ticker
    return arrival
```

The ticker is the current time in the simulation.
Most of the time this runs fine and calculates the arrival times, but every now and then I get the following error at the math.trunc():

> Exception has occurred: OverflowError
>   cannot convert float infinity to integer

It appears the function returns an infinity value, but I have no idea why.
Help please.

(I'm using python 3.5.4 64-bit)

Comment: If `p` is 1, then there is no finite value `x` such that a value drawn from a poisson distribution has probability 1 of being less than `x`.

Comment: does the randint range include the upper bound?

Comment: It does if you're using the stdlib `random.randint`.

Comment: `numpy.random.randint` behaves differently. This is one of the reasons why a [mcve] is important - we have to guess your imports here.

Comment: I see. Sorry forgot to add the imports. I hope this is now a minimal reproducible example. Changing the range to randint(1,99) has solved the problem. Thank you for your help!